# how to query get max id from varchar type and the values in numeric?

Tags: php, mysql, max

i have table and column id, and the values are 1, 2 ,3,...,10,11,12,13. 
how to query get max id from varchar type ? i had try

```
select MAX(id) from table
```

but the result is 9, Please help ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the values are strings and it selecting the maximum string. You have to cast them to numbers first if you want them to sort numerically. You can use [CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) to do this:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(id, SIGNED)) FROM table
```

You can also use [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(id AS SIGNED)) FROM table
```

They do nearly the same thing except `CONVERT` has some additional options if you need them.

Comment: You've missed the `CAST` function out of your example

Comment: Which one is better that I chose from my question above?

Comment: @N4tanata, unless you need the extra functionality provided by CONVERT, it's really a matter of preference. Whichever one you like better.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the varchar to an integer - something like

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(id, SIGNED)) FROM table
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT MAX(id+0) FROM` table will do the trick