# adding serial number on string php

Tags: php

I have these codes:

```
    //ambil nomor surat maksimum pada tabel surat_keterangan
$query = "SELECT MAX(nomor_surat) as noMax FROM surat_keterangan";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$nomor = $row['noMax'];
    //ambil karakter nomor urut surat paling kiri sebanyak 1 karakter (0, 1)
$noUrut = (int) substr($nomor, 0, 1);
$noUrut++;

//mengambil bulan dan tahun dari tanggal surat
$bulan = substr($tgl_surat,3,2);
$tahun = substr($tgl_surat,6,4);

//membuat nomor surat
$nomor_surat = $noUrut."/SK/".$bulan."/DPK3/".$tahun;
```

the output will be

> 1/SK/06/DPK3/2014.

the first string (1) will add every time I insert data.
I have tried until 10/SK/06/DPK3/2014, but when I continued to input, the output still

> 10/SK/06/DPK3/2014, not 11/SK/06/DPK3/2014.

is there another way?
thank you for every responses and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is on line with `$noUrut = (int) substr($nomor, 0, 1);` where you take alwazy the first character (when string begins with `10`, you take `1`only and `1++` makes 2.

So, you need to find first slash (/) position and than use substr.

```
$noUrut = (int)substr($nomor, 0, strpos($nomor, '/'));
$noUrut++;
```

OR just oneline

```
$noUrut = (int)substr($nomor, 0, strpos($nomor, '/')) + 1;
```

Comment: how about auto increment? can I use that?

Comment: Excuse me, there was a space between `strpos` and bracket. I updated my code, it works now. Use first two-line, or second one-line solution, both do the same.

Comment: You know, what´s the result of your query. try just `echo $nomor` if there is the string you expected. If so, than you have similar situation like this: `$nomor = '11/aaac';$noUrut = (int)substr($nomor, 0, strpos($nomor, '/')) + 1; echo $noUrut;` and it returns 12 (in string from database, there is 11, with substr&strpos I cut this number from my string and increment that).

Comment: I tried my query on phpmyadmin and the result is 9/SK/06/DPK3/2014 whereas there are 10 datas in it (10/SK/DPK3/2014).

Comment: I just tried to echo $nomor on php and the result is 9/SK/06/DPK3/2014. it stuck there. so when I keep input data, the result will always 10/SK/.... so I think there is a problem with my query.

Comment: Yes, there is problem. You store that as strings (char/varchar, etc.) and there are number compared as strings - 9 is after 10 (because you compare only first characters, 9 and 1). Possible solution: add new column where you will store only those numbers (and type of column has to be integer). Than you´ll find max in this new column (in integer comparason 9 is before 10 correctly).

Comment: I fix it with my query
$query = "SELECT nomor_surat AS noMax FROM surat_keterangan ORDER BY id_surat DESC LIMIT 1";
How about that? so I took the last record that just entered

Answer (score 1):

Is your field "nomor_surat" using varchar variable? if so then you need to convert it to int

[how to query get max id from varchar type and the values in numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391651/how-to-query-get-max-id-from-varchar-type-and-the-values-in-numeric)

Comment: please use comments next time you need clarification.

Comment: yes, "nomor_surat" is varchar. then if it need to convert into int, it should be

$query = "SELECT MAX(CONVERT(nomor_surat, SIGNED)) AS noMax FROM surat_keterangan";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$nomor = $row['noMax'];

Comment: is my query wrong? because it's still not working :(

Comment: owh, I know. I tried my query on phpmyadmin and the result is 9 (10 datas) because 9 is considered greater than 10 (so in 10, the query only took 1, without 0. so 9 is greater than 1). then how the query should be working on this? anyone help?

Comment: can you give an example values from nomor_surat... your query works fine ive tried it...

Comment: example values? 
this is format number of a letter = 1/SK/06/DPK3/2014 which are SK and DPK3 are default character, 06 is month of the letter date, 2014 is year of the letter date. I just think to get max value from "nomor_surat" column. if there is no data, then the format number should be 1/SK/... (it saved on "nomor_surat" column). then continued 2/SK/... 3/SK/...

Comment: I have tried these codes:
$noUrut = (int)substr($nomor, 0, strpos ($nomor, '/')) + 1;
with my query and it still stuck on 10.

Comment: use this "select MAX(CONVERT(LEFT(nomor_surat,(LOCATE('/',nomor_surat)-1)),SIGNED)) as no_max from surat_keterangan"